# Regex Replacement in Atom editor

Tags: php, regex, atom-editor

I want to replacement `$_POST["type"];` to `strip_tags($_POST["type"]);` (I want to filter all html tags in user's `POST` action)

But I have more than 200 `$_POST` in my whole project, like

```
$_POST["role"];
$_POST["uesrname"];
```

How to add this function using Regex?

Comment: I bet you have already tried a few times. Any chance you can share some of those fails with us?

Comment: I tried searching `\$_POST\[".{1,50}"\];`, and I got 232 results, but I can't surround it with strip_tags() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to search for the following regex:

```
(\$_POST\["[^"]+"])
```

And replace with:

```
strip_tags($1)
```

### Explanation

```
(): Capture the value to use it in the replace as `$1`
\$_POST: Locate the `$_POST` and the backslash to escape the `$`
\[]: Escape the opening square bracket
": Start of the quotes
\[^"]+: Take whatever inside that is not a quote
```

### Before

```
$_POST["type"]
$_POST["role"]
$_POST["username"]
```

### After

```
strip_tags($_POST["type"])
strip_tags($_POST["role"])
strip_tags($_POST["username"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex here,- call strip in a loop for every POST variable:

```
$postFiltered = [];
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  $postFiltered[] = strip_tags($_POST[$k]);
}
```

Comment: I recommend not doing this.  Every project I've ever witnessed that altered POST or GET values has regretted it.  You will never be able to get back the original posted value.  Use a separate filtered post variable if you want to go this route.

Comment: Agree with @Matt. But the function won't work anyways when you replace value with strip_tags of keys. EDIT: sorry my bad. I read it wrong. But I still agree with Matt